# Setting up central git repo on local Mac network

Tags: git, remote

We are a team of three, all working on our local machines on the same internal network.

We will all be working on websites in local working copies of the same Git repo hosted on Github.

We have an internal staging machine here (dev.internal), and I am looking for a way for us to be able to push to this machine. At each milestone in the development cycle.

In essence, all I really want us to be able to do is add the dev.internal machine as a remote, and push to this whenever we are ready.

Could somebody please point me in the right direction to get this set up?

Answer (score 3):

```
git add remote devinternal <remoteurl>
git push devinternal master:master
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, so should <remoteurl> be the file path? Eg: /Volumes/username/Sites/testdomain.internal ?

Comment: `<remoteurl>` should be whatever URL is required to access the central git repository.